# How to get Wi-Fi details from menubar in Big Sur like before?

Tags: wifi, big-sur, menu-bar

In previous versions of macOS it was possible to get details of the current Wi-Fi connection by <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> clicking the Wi-Fi icon in the menubar. This would show the ip address, WiFi strength, Wi-Fi frequency etc. None of the system icons react to this type of clicking anymore in Big Sur.

Here is a screenshot of how it used to look:

[image: Example Screenshot]

Is it possible to restore this behaviour or get something comparable?

Comment: Are you saying that if you show **Wi-Fi** by itself on the **menu bar** and then _**option-click**_ it, it does not show as in previous version of **macOS**?  To show the **Wi-Fi** by itself on the **menu bar**, have a look at [Show Wi-Fi status in the menu bar on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/mac-help/mchlp1244/11.0/mac/11.0).

Comment: I can confirm that if you option+click on the Wi-Fi menu bar extra in Big Sur, then it will continue to show this information, as it has in the past.

Comment: Oh my god I feel stupid... thank you @TJLuoma! Apparently they changed the shortcut. You answered my question.

Comment: I don’t think Apple changed the shortcut, it's always been _**option-click**_

Comment: My experience is something definitely changed about the menubar, because I always used command+option+click to get the detailed view. And now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I've have to admit that I've only been using an **Apple** computer for 15 years and in that time its been _**option-click**_. Even the ~10 year old [article from which the picture in you OP is from](https://osxdaily.com/2011/06/15/get-detailed-wifi-info-from-the-menu-bar/) states, "To do this, **hold down the Option key and then click on the WiFi menu icon** found on the Mac."   The _**option**_ _key_ has been the standard _key_ in **macOS** to get alternate _commands_ for menus and items in **System Preferences**, etc. No **⌘** _key_ required! in the use case!

Comment: The important thing is that it's working for the OP. Yes, you are correct that the only key that has been required is _option_. That being said: I checked on my Mac mini running an older version of macOS, and if you use ⌘⌥+click it works, however, if you use ⌘⌥+click on Big Sur, it _does not work._ So if TomTom had been in the habit of using ⌘⌥+click, he would have found that it did not work on Big Sur. So you are correct that they did not change the shortcut and TomTom is correct that the shortcut he had previously been using no longer works. Is all good now?

Answer (score 3):

Just to give this an answer for future searchers…

The key command was always Opt/click.

In the past, Cmd/Opt/click would also work - just by accident really.
In Big Sur, it no longer does work, so you have to use the prescribed command - Opt/click.

Answer (score -1):

Before you click on the WLAN symbol in the menu bar, please press the option button.  But you can also regulate the whole thing via the terminal.  Here is an order

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I
```